# Coldfusion10 via war on pre-existing Tomcat 7, web.xml

Tags: coldfusion, tomcat7, liferay

I've deployed the cfusion.war on a pre-existing tomcat instance also hosting Liferay(6.1.x). Both are in the webapps directory. I had to work through some issues related to taglib in the web.xml of the deployed cfusion.war. But it finally deployed without errors. Now I have the issue that tomcat doesn't know what to do with a .cfm (causing the browser prompting for download of http://my.liferayserver.edu/cfusion/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm instead of rending it with coldfusion). I think I have to do some servlet mapping in the "main" /tomcat/conf/web.xml (not /webapps/cfusion/WEB-INF/web.xml)

I've seen the few blogs, forum posts and other searchable information on this. It looks like CF10 can run fronted by Apache and using mod_jk.so, but I can't do this as it will probably mess with the Liferay instance I'm using ( it's delivered with a vendor's portal product).

Any thoughts on how to configure the pre-existing (not deployed with CF) tomcat instance web.xml to map to CF servlets in the deployed cfusion.war would be greatly appreciated.